# I am working on asp core and applying validation on some of my properties.but it is not properly working

Tags: asp.net-core

Actually I am using `ModelState.IsValid` and due to this my every property's value is required. But I applied Required annotation on some of my properties. So, When I don't pass any value to non required attibutes, My `ModelState.IsValid` becomes false.
Why??

Comment: Post your code. How in the world are we supposed to determine what the issue is if we can't see the code that's supposedly not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try to examine ModelState object while debugging. You can get which property or error causing it to fail.

[image]

Comment: I know which property is failing but I am not understanding .Why?

Comment: I explain you properly.

Comment: I have 4 text fields ie. Name, Description,ShortOrder,CreatedBy I applied Required Annotation on Name and Description but When I execute my project and inspect the ShortOrder and CreatedBy fields then .............. .data-val-required="The ShortOrder Field is required". and                     
data-val-required="The CreatedBy Field is required".  Why??